# How to set cursor position with Jquery using focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with my function. I made a text editor with BBcode.

Its working very well but the cursor always get back to the end of the textarea.

Here is how it works;

```
var element = document.getElementById('textEdit');
var lastFocus;
$(document.body).on('click','.editBout', function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
var style = ($(this).attr("data-style")); 
// Depending on the button I set the BBcode
    switch (style) {
        case 'bold':
            avS = "[b]";
            apS = "[/b]";
            break;
    }
    if (lastFocus) {
        setTimeout(function () { lastFocus.focus() }, 10);
        var textEdit = document.getElementById('textEdit');
        var befSel = textEdit.value.substr(0, textEdit.selectionStart);
        var aftSel = textEdit.value.substr(textEdit.selectionEnd, textEdit.length);
        var select = textEdit.value.substring(textEdit.selectionStart, textEdit.selectionEnd);
        textEdit.value = befSel + avS + select + apS + aftSel;
        textEdit = textEdit.value
        textEdit = BBcoder(textEdit);
        document.getElementById('editorPreview').innerHTML = textEdit;
    }
    return (false);
});
```

This last part here triggers the preview event

```
$(document.body).on('blur', '#textEdit', function() {
   lastFocus = this;
});
```

So i want it to come back to last focus but at a given position computed out of my selection + added bbcode length.

Comment: You'd generally use the `mousedown` event on the button to capture the `activeElement` and the cursor position, and then change the content to add the tags etc. Then, on the `mouseup` event, you reset the focus and the cursor position to what it was previously, accounting for the added markup etc.

Comment: Good idea will try that Thanks